# looking for a movie title – Chinese martial arts (pre-2000)

Tags: story-identification, b-movies, martial-arts

l-o-n-g time searching for an old Chinese movie (english dubbed) about a man who accidentally entered a higher realm where flamboyantly-dressed 'gods' (much like Stargate Goa'ulds) were playing a board game and their board game moves were acted out in real life. each god controlled a region of people, and when certain gods didn't get along, their earth-regions were also in conflict and didn't know why. after witnessing this, the main charter returned to his normal/mortal realm and tried to inform others (unsuccessfully) to not react or play along with the gods game. in the very end, he managed to return to the gods realm and then went even beyond it (suggesting another higher-level of gods).

i think the title contained 'sorcerer' or 'wizard'. i originally saw via Netflix DVD in early 2000's and wasn't able to find it again (Netflix software update erased watch history). a zillion google searches over many years and reading tons of martial art movie descriptions yielded no results.

Comment: Was suspecting a Sun Wukong/Monkey King martial arts film, but both *The Forbidden Kingdom* and *The Monkey King* came out well after 2000.

Comment: true, it was older than these wonderful movies, and much lower budget.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be the 1993 film *'[Green Snake](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106559/)'* starring Maggie Cheung?

> Two snake spirits become human and learn about love and suffering. A monk discovers his own weaknesses and finds that morality is not as simple as he had thought.

Comment: thanks for including the trailer, but 'Green Snake' wasn't it. 
the main character was an everyday citizen just trying to convince other townspeople that everyone was being manipulated by the whim of a gods game. scenes switched back-n-forth from gods playing board game to everyday life that they were affecting.